# How to readd removed columns in gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I am just having a problem on how should i add again a removed column in a gridview. I had an application that for example when you choose 1 the other columns are hidden and when you choose 2 the hidden columns should appear, I tried making it visible true and false but another problem occurs when i export its data to excel all other hidden columns are being saved also in excel because the columns are only hidden, so I come up on searching about how can i add again the removed column ,hope you can help me with this. This is how i remove the columns.

```
Public Sub RemoveGridColumn(ByRef Data As GridView, ByVal colName As String)
    For x As Integer = 0 To Data.Columns.Count - 1
        If Data.Columns(x).HeaderText = colName Then
            Data.Columns.RemoveAt(x)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the `DataBind` method of the `GridView` control before you hide the columns you do not want exported to Excel, something along the lines of this:

```
Protected Sub btnExportExcel_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    '' Set response settings here (header, content type, etc.)

    '' Turn paging off so you get all the rows of the grid
    GridView1.AllowPaging = False

    '' Make sure to bind before you hide anything
    GridView1.DataBind()

    '' Put logic here to hide columns that need to be hidden
    '' Possible from Session/ViewState, etc.


    '' Render out to response

End Sub
```

For a complete code example (in VB.NET and C#), then look at [ASP.NET GridView Export to Excel - Hide Columns](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-GridView-Export-to-Excel---Hide-Columns.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Please consider using CSS to set the visibility for the print:

```
@media print {
.noPrint {
    display:none;
  }
}
```

The code part during databound event should be something like:

```
Data.Columns(x).ItemStyle.CssClass = "noPrint"
```

In this way you can use javascript to change also printing visibility:

```
function hideColumn()
{
    col_num = document.getElementById("ColumnToChange").value;
    rows = document.getElementById("GridViewId").rows;
    for(i=0;i<maxrow;i++) {
       rows[i].cells[col_num].style.display="none";
    }
}
```